# Django. Map field from model to field in database table

Tags: django

I've got the following model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    field_one = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    field_two = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "super_table"
```

and the following database table:

```
CREATE TABLE public.super_table
(
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('super_table_id_seq'::regclass),
  field_two character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  field_three character varying(255) NOT NULL,
)
```

can I somehow to map `field_one` in model with `field_three` in my `super_table`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you can with db_column

> Field.db_column   The name of the database column to use for this
>   field. If this isn’t given, Django will use the field’s name.
>
> If your database column name is an SQL reserved word, or contains
>   characters that aren’t allowed in Python variable names – notably, the
>   hyphen – that’s OK. Django quotes column and table names behind the
>   scene

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    field_one = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_column='field_three')
    field_two = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "super_table"
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use the [`db_column`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#db-column) argument.

```
field_one = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_column='field_three')
```